# Office 2013 updates with office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office

I am getting office 2013 updates with office 2010. I don't know whether to install them or not. Office is kms activated. I had first tried to install 2013 but it did not work on 8.1. It gave a error so i gave up and installed 2010 but i get office 2013 updates with 2010. What to do??

Answer (score -1):

Have you deleted Office 2013 completely? Office is kinda deeply rooted into the system and it is really annoying to delete everything by hand. I think you could reinstall the operating system. It is always the most effective way to solve the problem. Hope that helps!